# how to use Flash code completion?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

At this years Flash on the beach i saw a speaker using small 'code-keywords' that would complete entire sets of AS-code, depending on the keyword.

Ex.:
He would write @forloop, hit enter/space and a typical for-loop would be written automatically.

Unfortunately he never said how to access this functionality in Flash.

Can anyone tell me what this is called and how to set it up in Flash Professional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flash Professional is about the worst ActionScript editor you will find.

What you speak of, are snippets, and it's supported by any decent editor in one form or another. My personal favourite is [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/), where snippets are triggered using Ctrl+B by default.
You might also consider FDT or a number of other editors.

Comment: Well, working alot with graphics i find it comfortable switching between tabs in Flash rather then programs in windows. Guess it's a question of habit. Maybe i'll give FlashDevelop another shot

Comment: @VoodooBurger: I understand that. However, as projects grow bigger, you will have trouble organizing all source files without a proper IDE. Flash Professional is first and foremost a graphics and animation tool. Also investing the money for a second screen to have FlashDevelop on one and Flash Professional on the other is totally worth it, given how cheap screens are nowadays.

Comment: Don't forget Flash Builder, which now has way better code generation tools than FlashDevelop

Comment: @AmyBlankenship: Yes, Flash Builder is also worth mentioning. However you are misinformed, if you believe it's code generation to be *better* (let alone *way better*). It follows a different philosophy. Whether it's *better* is subjective. From my experience, it's a lot slower. Many options are somewhere in the second level of a context menu and waste even more time by open dialogues. Yet I can't rule out, that some people might actually be faster with that. I'd be really careful making blanket statements like that, especially when implicitly advertising commercial software.